# Is there a way to retrieve all salesforce usernames and orgs attached to my email?

Tags: email, user, org, developer-org, username

Just wondering if we can get all usernames (SF username and Orgs) attached to my email. According to [this article](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000004229&type=1) only way seems to get help from Administrator.

Appreciate if someone had the same requirement solved, and could help please. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are in general looking to find details associated to your email then below may help —

If you have partner support available with Salesforce then you may have luck. They will be able to provide you the username and associated org with a particular email. I have had a case with support on some other issue and during resolution of that case, Salesforce support was able to find all usernames associated with one of my email ids. This was almost 2 years back but always good to check with the support.

---

If you are looking to get it from different sandboxes associated to a production instance —

There is **no out of the box** way to get your username associated to your email from different sandboxes. To be able to get your username from different sandboxes associated with same production instance, you will need to have a system admin do that for you (unless you remember all your credentials, which would mean you already know it).